# Slider are moving only at first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Slides moves with mouse only at first time, I mean even if you change slide and then change it back it doesn't move again, it's look like onmousemove works only at first attempt and then crushes, any idea what is the problem? thanks in advance .

*I marked these parts of the code by writing (doesn't work).*

If you click on #second-section and move mouse (right,left), slides also go (right,left), when you move mouse further slide changes, and this is the moment that my problem appears, you click again on #second-section div and move (right,left) slides doesn't move at all (but yes you still can change the slide). You can see it more accurately when you change "ratio" variable to 3

html

```
<div id="second-section">
    <div class="project-slide"></div>
    <div class="project-slide"></div>
    <div class="project-slide"></div>
    <div class="project-slide"></div>
    <div class="project-slide"></div>
    <div class="project-slide"></div>
    <div class="project-slide"></div>


    <div onclick="changeSliderLeft()" id="section_arrow-left" class="section_arrow-left">
        &larr;
    </div>

    <div onclick="changeSliderRight()" id="section_arrow-right" class="section_arrow-right">
        &rarr;
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
<style>
    *
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #second-section
    {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: darkslategrey;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        perspective: 1000px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #second-section .project-slide
    {
        height: 50%;
        width: 48%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(1)
    {
        background-color: red;
        left: -24%;
        transform: rotateY(30deg)
    }
    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(2)
    {
        background-color: blue;
        left: 26%;
        transform: rotateY(0deg)
    }
    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(3)
    {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        left: 76%;
        transform: rotateY(-30deg)
    }
    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(4)
    {
        background-color: yellow;
        left: 126%;
    }
    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(5)
    {
        background-color: green;
        left: 176%;
    }
    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(6)
    {
        background-color: white;
        left: 226%;
    }
    #second-section .project-slide:nth-of-type(7)
    {
        background-color: black;
        left: 276%;
    }


     #second-section .section_arrow-left 
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 40%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #second-section .section_arrow-right 
    { 
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        right: 40%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

js/jquery

```
//middle element
var slidePosition=1;

var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("project-slide");
var countSlide = document.querySelectorAll("#second-section .project-slide").length;
var distanceBetweenSlides = getLeftEdgePosition(1)-getLeftEdgePosition(0);

var slidePositionTab = Array(countSlide);
for(i=0; i<countSlide; i++)
{
    slidePositionTab[i]=getLeftEdgePosition(i);
}

var animationTime = 850;

function changeSliderLeft()
{
    //works as long as middle slide is not first one
    if(slidePosition!=0)
    {
        slidePosition--;

        //new elements positions
        for(i=0; i<countSlide; i++)
        {
            //starting left edge position - distance between left edges
            slide[i].style.left=slidePositionTab[i]+distanceBetweenSlides+"%";
            slide[i].style.transition=animationTime+"ms ease-in-out";

            slidePositionTab[i]+=distanceBetweenSlides;
        } 

        //rotation
        if(slidePosition==0)
        {
            rotate(slidePosition,0);
            rotate(slidePosition+1,-30);
        }
        else
        {
            if(slidePosition-1<countSlide)
                rotate(slidePosition-1,30);
            if(slidePosition<countSlide)
                rotate(slidePosition,0);
            if(slidePosition+1<countSlide)
                rotate(slidePosition+1,-30);
        }
    }
}

function changeSliderRight()
{
    //works as long as middle slide is not last one
    if(slidePosition<countSlide-1)
    {
        if (slidePosition!=countSlide)
            slidePosition++;

        ///new elements positions
        for(i=0; i<countSlide; i++)
        {
            //starting left edge position - distance between left edges
            slide[i].style.left=slidePositionTab[i]-distanceBetweenSlides+"%";
            slide[i].style.transition=animationTime+"ms ease-in-out";

            slidePositionTab[i]-=distanceBetweenSlides;
        } 

        //rotation
        if(slidePosition-1<countSlide)
            rotate(slidePosition-1,30);
        if(slidePosition<countSlide)
            rotate(slidePosition,0);
        if(slidePosition+1<countSlide)
            rotate(slidePosition+1,-30);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
//            D R A G                   //
/////////////////////////////////////////
//            D R A G                  //
/////////////////////////////////////////
//            D R A G                  //
/////////////////////////////////////////


//slide changes after 1/ratio of its width
var slideWidth = $(".project-slide:eq("+slidePosition+")").width();
var ratio = 7; 

var currentMousePositionInsideSection;
var mousePositionInsideSection;

$("#second-section").on('mousedown', function(e) 
{    
    //u can only by clicking on middle slideslides)

    //offset left position of all slides  (doesn't work)
    var mousePositionInsideSlidesTab = Array(countSlide)
    for(i=0; i<countSlide; i++)
    {
        mousePositionInsideSlidesTab[i]= e.pageX - $(".project-slide:eq("+i+")").offset().left;
    }

    //mouse starting x cord in section
    mousePositionInsideSection = e.pageX - $("#second-section").offset().left;

    //start moving
    $("#second-section").on('mousemove', function(e) 
    {
        //mouse current x cord in section
        currentMousePositionInsideSection = e.pageX - $("#second-section").offset().left;

        //move slides (doesn't work)
        for(i=0; i<countSlide; i++)
        {
            newPosition(i,currentMousePositionInsideSection-mousePositionInsideSlidesTab[i]);
        }

        //check if diffrence between starting and current position is higher than slide width/ratio
        if(mousePositionDifference().positionDifference>(slideWidth/ratio))
        {
            //stop moving
            $("#second-section").off("mousemove");

            //restrict starting position mouse higher than curret to 1

            //check mouse move direction
            if(mousePositionDifference().direction == "left")
            {
                changeSliderLeft();
            }
            else if(mousePositionDifference().direction == "right")
            {
                changeSliderRight();
            }
        }
    })
}).on("mouseup", function() 
{
    $("#second-section").off("mousemove");

    //back to starting slides position if diffrence between starting and current position is smaller than slide width/ratio  (doesn't work)
    if(mousePositionDifference().positionDifference<=(slideWidth/ratio))
    {
        for(i=0; i<countSlide; i++)
            slide[i].style.left=slidePositionTab[i]+"%";
    }
});



function getLeftEdgePosition(n)
{
    //left edge position of slider number (a)
    var left = slide[n].offsetLeft;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var startingPosition = Math.round(100 * left / windowWidth);
    return startingPosition;
}

//rotate n element rot degres
function rotate(n,rot)
{
    slide[n].style.transform="rotateY("+rot+"deg)";
}

//diffrence between starting mouse position and current mouse position relatively to middle slide and mouse move direction 
function mousePositionDifference()
{
    var direction;
    var positionDifference=0;

    if(mousePositionInsideSection>currentMousePositionInsideSection)
    {
        positionDifference=mousePositionInsideSection-currentMousePositionInsideSection;
        direction = "right";

        return {positionDifference,direction};
    }
    else if (mousePositionInsideSection<currentMousePositionInsideSection)
    {
        positionDifference = currentMousePositionInsideSection-mousePositionInsideSection;
        direction = "left";

        return {positionDifference,direction};
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

//move n element('name') to position x
function newPosition(n,x)
{
    $(".project-slide:eq("+n+")").offset(
        {
            left: x,
        });
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Everything works well using your code.

Comment: Same here, all working, apart from arrow buttons. I copied your code directly into a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1db7aov8

Comment: If you click on #second-section and move mouse (right,left), slides also go (right,left), when you move mouse further slide changes, and this is the moment that my problem appears, you click again on #second-section div and move (right,left) slides doesn't move at all (but yes you still can change the slide). I've checked this  fiddle you can see it more accurately when you change "ratio" variable to 3

Comment: I don't know if topics are closed here, but I finally fixed it